# passing parameter from a tag to lightbox

Tags: php, html, wordpress, parameter-passing, lightbox

I'm using a [lightbox plugin](http://www.23systems.net/wordpress-plugins/lightbox-plus-for-wordpress/) to display a page with dynamic content in a lightbox, I need to pass a parameter `id` from the **< a >** tag to the lightbox content.

This is the **< a >** tag

```
<a href="#?pid=<?php echo $image->pid;?>" class="lbp_singe-image">
```

And this is the lightbox content that will be displayed when I click on the link.

```
<div style="display:none">
    <div id="lbp_singe-image">
        <?php
            $pid = $_GET["pid"];  //I need to get the ID
            $pid = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $pid);
            $shortcode_output = do_shortcode('[singlepic id="' . $pid . '" w="" h=""]');
            if ($shortcode_output=="[SinglePic not found]"){
                echo ("No picture here");  
            }else {
                echo do_shortcode('[singlepic id="' . $pid . '" w="" h=""]');
            }
        ?>
    </div>  
</div>
```

The lightbox is working correctly, 
My problem is that I want to fetch the value from the link.

so what can I do here?

---

**Update**

It is a gallery page, contains many anchors, each anchor has `$image->pid;` the shortcode supposed to run in separated page where the URL is full and ***php*** will be able to fetch the value with `$_GET["pid"]`, but I need to run it in a lightbox instead and here where I can't use the url to get the ID.

[image: preview]

Comment: What is it giving right now ?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `#` with the absolute URL for the site?

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner It is giving "No picture here", because it failed to get the ID

Comment: @rnevius Yes I tried to replace with `#` but the result is the same, since the php couldn't catch the ID

Comment: Is it showing in the URL ?

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner Nope, It is a lightbox, url won't change I need another way to pass a parameter maybe

Comment: So the page doesn't actually refresh or redirect, then the $_GET wouldn't exist. you already have the id on the server ' $image->pid' so why try to get it frmo somewhere else?

Comment: @atmd what about the other attributes of the tag <a> like rel, title .. etc

Comment: @atmd It is a gallery page contains many <a> tags, and each one has its own ID, the lightbox should receive the ID of the clicked link.

Comment: Full code will be great !

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner I posted all what you need to know, I just need someone to explain to me what options do I have to pass a parameter, it is not even possible to post the full code here man.

Comment: You can post the code in pastebin and give us to link and you are very unclear. Why can't you use `echo $image->pid;` in `echo do_shortcode('[singlepic id="' . $pid . '" w="" h=""]');` ? Other thing as you have mentioned that there are lot of gallery then there must be some foreach loop so if you provide more code then I can help you.

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner I mentioned in the comment above, It is a gallery page, contains many anchors, each anchor has `$image->pid;` the shortcode supposed to run in different page, I'm planning to run it in a lightbox instead and here where I can't use the url to get the ID, did you get it?

Comment: You still did not get... If you want the content in the same page with light box, it simply means you need to write code in same page.So if you are writing in same page you can get it with ` echo do_shortcode('[singlepic id="' . $image->pid . '" w="" h=""]'); ` .Am I right ?

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner yes, but how can you tell which `$image->pid` there will be 20 -30 of it, I updated the question can you see?

Comment: Why don't you use AJAX ?

Answer (score 0):

The way you use the lightbox no request will be sent to the server, instead you display a content div that already is on the same page. That is why `$_GET['pid']` is empty at that moment.

I see 2 possible solutions.

First, instead of `$_GET['pid']` you use `$image->pid`.

Second, if you want to send a request to the server when the link is clicked, use the technique described in the docs chapter "Secondary Lightbox General Usage":

http://www.23systems.net/wordpress-plugins/lightbox-plus-for-wordpress/demos/

> A secondary lightbox can be used to display internal and external web pages, video or interactive flash. Secondary lightboxes must be set up manually and can use either a rel=”lightbox[id]” attribute or a class=”lbpModal” attribute to associate the link/content with the a lightbox.

So something like this should work:

```
<a class="lbpModal" href="[urlToScriptThatGeneratesYourContent]">click</a>
```

**Note:** I never used this plugin, nor have I tested this, it is just what I read from the docs.

Comment: exactly, I'm using a secondary lightbox, I'm saying the lightbox is working correctly the only difference that I can't get the ID when I use a lightbox

Comment: read the docs, you need either the rel attribute or the class lpbModal for secondary lightbox

Comment: you misunderstand the question, I don't have a problem with the lightbox. please read my question, the lightbox is working fine, the problem is explained

Comment: I'm not saying that the lightbox isn't working, but with your current technique you don't send a request to the server, thus no $_GET. Read my answer ;)

Comment: I know that but I need a solution

Comment: You seem resistant to advice. Use the class lbpModal for content that isn't already on the page.